# How to increment div height/paddint-top on scrolling and detect an image collision to the div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Text is scrolling and I can stop the text based on a fixed scroll value.

But the Home div height is 100vh, so not all screen resolution will stop the text in the same scroll value. So I need to stop dynamically when it reach certain scroll value which may be different in other resolutions. (or stop when reach some #Element)

Moreover I need to make the description div paddingTop increase the value while scrolling to insert the Text inside that div, and stop increasing height and stop the text moving when it reach some point, according to previous parragraph explanation.

I'm up to use some effect libraries or whatever,but prefering to do with vanilla-js, is nice to learn how it works.

I did this example: https://jsfiddle.net/ja0hzydw/4/

**HTML**

```
<section name="Home" id="home">
  <div class="home">
    <div class="logo" id="logo">
      <p>T</p>
      <p>E</p>
      <p>X</p>
      <p>T</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section name="Description" id="description">
  <div class="description">
    <div class="description-title" id="descTitle">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>
    <div class="description-text">
      <p id="descParagraph1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ultricies massa ac sem aliquam, et convallis est feugiat. Nunc ut diam orci. Nunc sed malesuada tortor. Donec orci diam, ultricies eget magna auctor, facilisis elementum metus.                  
      </p>
      <p id="descParagraph2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ultricies massa ac sem aliquam, et convallis est feugiat. Nunc ut diam orci. Nunc sed malesuada tortor.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.home {
    background-image: url("https://www.wallpapertip.com/wmimgs/0-236_440px-animated-wallpaper-windows.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(calc(50vw - 50%), calc(50vh - 50%));
}

.description {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 550px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    scrollLogo();
};

function scrollLogo() {
    var element = document.getElementById("logo");
    var scrollValue = 80;
    if (document.body.scrollTop > scrollValue || document.documentElement.scrollTop > scrollValue) {
        element.style.marginTop = "80px";
        element.style.position = "absolute";
    } else {
        element.style.marginTop = "0px";
        element.style.position = "fixed";
    }
    var descriptionHeight = document.getElementById("descTitle");
    descriptionHeight.style.padding = "50px 0px 0px 0px";
    console.log("document.body.scrollTop", document.body.scrollTop, "document.documentElement.scrollTop", document.documentElement.scrollTop);
}
```

Comment: IntersectionObserver is useful here - it will let you know when a particular element comes into or goes out of the viewport so it doesn't rely on scroll value - ie independent of device dimensions.

Comment: I will look about it but what about incresing the height of description div?